# Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor in js.erb file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm trying to changes the `src` attribute of my img(s) when they are hovered over using jQuery. But I am getting an error saying ,`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'icon_history'`

app.js.erb

```
 var hover = <%= image_path 'icon_history-h1' %>;

  var unhover = <%= image_path 'icon_history' %>;

  $('img.more').hover(function(){
    console.log(hover);
    $(this).attr('src', hover);
  },
  function(){
    console.log(unhover);
    $(this).attr('src', unhover);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape strings and put them to quotes:

```
var hover = '<%= j image_path 'icon_history-h1' %>';

var unhover = '<%= j image_path 'icon_history' %>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is your case or not, but I had similar issue:

> SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'u'

I fixed it simply by updating Node.js in my Ubuntu server.
Previous version was:

```
$ node -v
v5.1.1
```

Then I did:

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
   ... long output
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
   ... shorter output
$ node -v
v6.7.0
```

And no more issues.